# Components of a vector, given it's XY projection and it's angle with the z-axis

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

> A unit vector **u** makes angle *a* with the z-axis. It's projection onto the XY plane makes angle *b* with the x-axis. What is the unit vector expressed in terms of *a* and *b*?

I've been trying to find it by working out the direction cosines of **u** and it's projection vector but I'm stuck.

Edit:
Here's what I know so far...

The projection vector **p** has direction cosines cos(*b*) and cos(90-*b*) for the x and y-axes. The z-component of **u** will be cos(*a*). But I'm not sure how to use the projection unit vector's components (cos(*b*), cos(90-*b*), 0) to get the components of **u** only in terms of *a* and *b*.

Edit2:
Never-mind, I was able to figure it out. You just multiply the projection vector components by sin(a) and they'll be the correct **u** components. So the vector **u** would be (sin(a)cos(b), sin(a)sin(b), coz(a)).

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: You can find its component on the z-axis through $\cos(a)$. You can then find the components on the x- and y-axes through $u_p\cos(b)$ and $u_p\cos(\pi/2-b)$, respectively, where $u_p$ is the orthogonal projection in  the $xy$ plane